# ZF2 Authentication

Tags: authentication, zend-framework2

i am developing an application using ZF2. I have done the user authentication with username & password. But, i would like to check an additional column(example: status) in authentication.

I have done the following codes.

```
public function authenticate()
{       
    $this->authAdapter = new AuthAdapter($this->dbAdapter,
            'usertable',
            'username',
            'password'
    );  

    $this->authAdapter->setIdentity($this->username)
                ->setCredential($this->password)
                ->setCredentialTreatment('MD5(?)');
    $result = $this->authAdapter->authenticate();
    return $result;
}
```

How can i check the column 'status' in authentication? 
Note: status value should be 1.
Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When I was building my authentication using zf2 and doctrine, I have created authorization plugin and customized [this adapter](https://gist.github.com/4604528) for passing extra column for authentication. 
You probably need to go on similar directions.

```
$adapter = new AuthAdapter($db,
                           'users',
                           'username',
                           'password',
                           'MD5(?)'
                           );

// get select object (by reference)
$select = $adapter->getDbSelect();
$select->where('active = "TRUE"');

// authenticate, this ensures that users.active = TRUE
$adapter->authenticate();
```

[Reference](https://packages.zendframework.com/docs/latest/manual/en/modules/zend.authentication.adapter.dbtable.html)

After changes your code should look something like this.

```
public function authenticate()
{       
    $this->authAdapter = new AuthAdapter($this->dbAdapter,
            'usertable',
            'username',
            'password'
    );  

    $select = $this->authAdapter->getDbSelect();
    $select->where('status= "1"');
    $this->authAdapter->setIdentity($this->username)
                ->setCredential($this->password)
                ->setCredentialTreatment('MD5(?)');
    $result = $this->authAdapter->authenticate();
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: @Developer You're not really using MD5 as credential treatment, are you?

Comment: @Daniel I always use CredentialTreatment, but user2003356 might not using it, above answer is reply based on question.

Answer (score 1):

ZF2 provides a another way to handle additional checks using other columns than the ones foreseen for identity and credential thanks to the method `getResultRowObject`. All columns of  `usertable` in your example are available as properties of the object returned by `getResultRowObject()`. So you could expand your code with this :

```
if ($result->isValid()) {
    $identityRowObject = $this->authAdapter->getResultRowObject();
    $status = $identityRowObject->status;
    // do whatever complex checking you need with $status...
}
```

Regards,
Marc